# xgettext with keyword that contains special characters

Tags: xgettext

How can keywords be escaped when passing the --keyword argument? We use static calls to fetch translations, i.e. in the form Language::getText('foo');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid you only have three options:

1. Write your own custom tool to extract strings from this sort of code.
2. Realize you are using a gettext library that has certain ways of doing thing and use it as it was intended to be used, i.e. with some sane, simple function or macro instead of a verbose `Language::getText` method call.
3. Add support for this to `xgettext` and submit a patch to GNU gettext project.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a solution to this as well; it looks (to my non-C-programming eyes) like xgettext uses colons as a separator internally. [According to a comment in the code](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/gettext/gettext-tools/src/x-php.c?root=gettext&revision=1.28&content-type=text/plain), "The characters between name and end should form a valid C identifier. A colon means an invalid parse in split_keywordspec()." So it's basically dumping anything with a colon in it as invalid.

Comment: Source in the *documentation*: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html#Language-specific-options